# Merge problem from forked git

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to merge changes from an updated git to my forked version and am running into failure notices in the fork queue (when I "apply" them).

Any ideas why this is happening? I think this has something to do with changing the files before successfully merging the updated git to my fork?

Comment: You're going to have to be a lot more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a purely GitHub issue (a problem on GitHub side), you need to:

- open a GitHub ticket
- follow [similar tickets advice](http://support.github.com/discussions/repos/2677-cannot-apply-commits-in-fork-queue) like:

> This is a known issue, **You'll have to merge or cherry-pick the commits locally** until we have a fix.

The OP confirms in the comment:

> I checked out GitHub support and found some useful stuff.
>   **I apparently needed to manually update each file that was causing the error and then push my changes back to my fork**.
>   Everything seems to work now.

Comment: I checked out GitHub support and found some useful stuff. I apparently needed to manually update each file that was causing the error and then push my changes back to my fork. Everything seems to work now :) Thanks.